# Should a community wiki post be made for cost per day?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Please keep an open mind while reading it (not to say those of you reading this don't have an open mind :)).

I was wondering if a community wiki page could be made for cost per day of a particular country under 2 or 3 different travel styles: backpacking, midrange, and high-end.

While everyone's travel style and costs are different, one solution to combat this may be to have users average in their costs for the countries they visited. While I understand it's not really TA's job to do these kinds of things, I think it would be extremely helpful vs. the alternatives. Sites such as wikitravel and Lonely Planet include costs per day, but just comparing a few countries (such as Finland), what wikitravel says is a minimum is not anywhere near what LP says is a minimum. I think this way, people can get averages and averages will include currency fluctuations as well. So it's a more updated view.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand what you are trying to do, and it's probably going to be of use to some, but that sort of question (if it is at all a question) is not what we do here on Travel-SE. Understand that this site is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site, and what you describe is not really a question -- more of a blog post/wiki page, or a discussion. If it were to be framed as an actual question, it runs afoul of at least a few guidelines about questions on Travel-SE:

- **It's too broad.** There are what, around 200 countries in the world. A post for each of them is clearly not going to work, nor it will mesh well with the SE format.
- **It's primarily opinion-based.** You define three categories for daily costs, however I'm certain there are different interpretations of them. Your mid-range is not the same as anybody else's mid-range. We all have our own travel styles, and while we skimp sometimes on certain things, we can spend lavishly on stuff we deeply care about. Myself, for example -- I am an avid cook and food appreciator, and tasting quality food abroad is one of the highlights of every journey, regardless of the particular travel reason. Hence, I tend to spend more on food than others, including visiting restaurants that are strictly high-end territory. Attempting to put people in categories is not going to work, and never did.

There's little that can be done to avoid those two problems -- what you are proposing is simply not what we do here on Travel-SE. One of the main reasons discussion-y and subjective questions are discouraged is to avoid lengthy diatribes and back-and-forths, where everybody seems to be correct. And usually it's not the people involved that are the problem, but the topic/question. Ever seen a forum thread with 50 pages or more? Have you ever told yourself "Hey, that's 50 pages of discussion, I'll just spend an hour to go through them to find the one bit of information I actually care about."? I myself sure have no patience to go beyond page 1 -- there are better uses for my time.

Quality and high signal-to-noise ratio is what we care about, and if that means certain questions or posts are not allowed, so be it.